# Help solving differential equation: $y' = x\sqrt{4+y^{2}}/{y(9+x^{2})}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I do not have an idea where to start to solve the following differential equation, so every tip is welcome.

$$y' = \frac{x\sqrt{4+y^{2}}}{y(9+x^{2})} $$

Comment: This differential equation is separable, meaning that you can get all the $x$ terms on one side and the $y$ terms on the other. Rewrite $y'$ as $\frac{dy}{dx}$, separate the $x$ terms from the $y$ terms (including $dx$ and $dy$ respectively), then integrate both sides. That will be a good start.

Comment: @Théophile, i understand how to solve differential equations, it's not my first, but i dont have idea how to separate x and y from this expression, because of its complexity

Comment: The right side of the equality can be written as $\frac{\sqrt{4+y^2}}{y} \frac{x}{(9+x^2)}$. Does this help?

Comment: @JavierBadia - thanks, it's a little late here in Europe (2:44AM), therefore slower i think :D

Answer (score 3):

We write your equation as
$$
\frac{y}{\sqrt{4+y^2}}dy=\frac{x}{9+x^2}dx
$$
or equivalenlently,
$$
d(\sqrt{4+y^2})=d((1/2)\ln(9+x^2)).
$$
Hence, we get
$$
\sqrt{4+y^2}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(9+x^2)+C.
$$